# WordPress jQuery attach image

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to attach an image using jQuery but have gotten a strange problem.

(please ignore the '+num+' as this is part of a loop)

```
var image   = jQuery("#Slide_image"+num).val();
jQuery('img[name="image_'+num+'_data"]').attr("src","http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg");
```

The above works fine, the below does not:

```
var image   = jQuery("#Slide_image"+num).val();
jQuery('img[name="image_'+num+'_data"]').attr("src",image);
```

HTML

```
<tr>
  <td>Image:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" size="36" name="SlideShow_0_image" value="" />
        <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
        <img style="float:right;" name='image_0_data' src=''  width='70' height='70' />
        <br />Enter an URL or upload an image for the banner.
    </td>
</tr>
```

Even though the image variable holds the same text

can anyone explain why?

Thanks
Eli

Comment: Post some html please.  I am wondering what html element #Slide_image1 is.

Comment: Looks like your selector for the `image` variable is wrong.  I don't see an input with an id that contains `Slide_image`...?

Comment: @Nal Thats because its looking at the name not the ID, like i said above it works if type in the text but does not work for the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure what the the problem was but it is now fixed, it might have had something do do with the cache.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var image   = jQuery("#Slide_image"+num).val();
```

Should be

```
var image   = jQuery('input[name="SlideShow_'+num+'_image"]').val();
```

When a selector starts with a `#` it is looking for an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the variable named image is not a URL... the element with ID #Slide_image1 is NOT visible in this HTML excerpt!!